# How to manually install pangloss JavaScript plugin?

Tags: filetype-javascript, plugin-managers

If possible, I would prefer to not start using a package manager for now.

I'm trying to *manually* install this plugin for editing JS files: https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript

I have looked around, and tested several things, but for some reason I can't get it to work.

How would you go about "manually" installing the *pangloss* plugin without using pathogen, or a package manager?

It's my first question here. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks! yes, I have a vim with packages support. Would be happy to hear about your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! It makes sense, and I can install _pangloss/vim-javascript_. It seems to work now!

Comment: I tried upvoting, but it seems I haven't enough rep. Will wait the ~24h for accepting an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, but of course. Apologies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TL;DR Use `:h packages`

You will need

- the plugin code (github is easiest, though if you just have a copy of the
  source tree lying around, that works too)

## A brief history of <strike>time</strike> managing plugins<sup>1</sup>

I won't go into extreme detail here unless it is requested. This is mostly a
background section, and can be skipped if needed.

In the dark ages, you used to need to put all plugin code next to each other, so
(for example) your `~/.vim/plugin` would have

- `plugin-a.vim`
- `unrelated-plugin-b.vim`
- etc.

Updating and removing plugins was a *nightmare*: what did you do if an update
removed a file? How did you know which files belonged with which plugins and
needed deletion?

Pathogen gave us `bundle` to keep things separate, and that's what packages do
too<sup>2</sup>.

Pathogen (typically) adds each directory under, e.g., `~/.vim/bundle` to the
`'runtimepath'`.  In other words, you could have

- `~/.vim/bundle/mypluginhere`, and
- `~/.vim/bundle/pangloss-javascript-here`

But you still managed those directories yourself. (Other plugin managers can do
that for you, but you don't need—or always want—that).

The advantage of this is described [Plugin layout in the Dark
Ages](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/42.html) and [A New
Hope: Plugin Layout with
Pathogen](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/43.html).

Packages bring to vim8 what pathogen had already done for previous vim versions,
and they do so natively. Packages provide a way of adding segmented components
to the `'runtimepath'` (remember that this path controls where vim looks for
plugin code, autoload scripts, filetype plugins, &c.).

### Enter packages

Packages use `'packpath'`, which is a bit like a combination of `bundle` and
`'runtimepath'`.

What *you* need to know is that you can put a complete copy of the plugin source
tree in `~/.vim/pack/<any-name-you-want>/start/<plugin-name>`. (The adept user
may want to investigate `opt` as well.)

That's it. It will be loaded for you by vim.

#### Some management strategies with `git`

1. `git-clone`: this strategy is for users who just want to clone the plugin and
   have it run. Typical interaction looks like

```
# git clone <path/to/repo> ~/.vim/pack/<other-plugins>/start/<plugin-name>
```

2. `git-submodule`: this strategy is for folks like me who keep their
   dotfiles/vim configs in version control. Typical interaction looks like

```
# git -C <dotfile-dir> submodule add <path/to/repo> <dotfile-vim-dir>/pack/<other-plugins>/start/<plugin-name>
```

---

1. I omit all plugin managers except pathogen, which is actually a
   `'runtimepath'` manager. This little lie won't hurt anyone, though.
2. They have a slightly broader use case. I'm aware, but I don't find it
   necessary for the purposes of this question.