# :GhostInstall does not work

Tags: installing

Note: I am fairly new to NeoVim. So far I have installed plugins by simply unzipping the plug-in master folder into the directory `/usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin`. In case there is no master folder I just move the pluginname.vim file to this directory. It has worked well until now.

I am trying to install the [GhostText plugin](https://github.com/raghur/vim-ghost) which goes with the [GhostText extension for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ghosttext/). I did it as before, by simply unzipping the plug-in master folder into the directory `/usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin`, so that now I have a directory called `vim-ghost-master` in that directory.

When I run a nvim session and run the command `:GhostInstall` (which does autocomplete), I get the following error:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manually install pangloss JavaScript plugin?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20979/how-to-manually-install-pangloss-javascript-plugin)

Comment: At a guess, the plugin directory is the wrong directory (i.e., there is a difference between a plugin on GitHub and what vim originally called a plugin; the former is a collection of cooperating scripts, while the latter is usually a single .vim file or two meant to be loaded on startup). See help plugin

Answer (score 1):

Just use [packages](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#packages) to install Vim plug-ins.

Simply create a directory `~/.vim/pack/something/start`, where "something" is literally anything, perhaps use your nickname "Soap".

Then unpack or git clone the plug-in tree there, so you get `~/.vim/pack/Soap/start/vim-ghost-master` and then you get the plug-in directories (`autoload`, `plugin`, `python3`) all there.

This would probably fix the plug-in, since it looks like it's failing to find the Python code, most likely because it's expecting to find it at the root of a plug-in directory, rather than somewhere inside a subdirectory of `plugin`.

If you're writing to the system location because you want the plug-in to be available to all users in your system, you can still use packages, just use the appropriate location, which it seems would be `/usr/share/nvim/site/pack` in NeoVim (`/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/pack` in Vim 8), and same scheme of creating a subdir (any name) and then `start/` under it. (See `:help 'packpath'` and `:help 'runtimepath'` for more information on these paths.)

Comment: Thank you, but I tried the first thing you said (I don't need to have this for all users) and it did not work. Same error as before...